# Rails 3 select random follower query efficiency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method that selects 5 random users who are following a certain user, and adds them to an array.

```
Relationship.find_all_by_followee_id( user.id ).shuffle[0,4].each do |follower|
   follower = User.find(follower.user_id)
   array.push follower
end
return array
```

I'm wondering, is this an efficient way of accomplishing this? My main concern is with the find_all_by_followee_id call. This returns a list of all the relationships where the specified user is being followed (this could be in the 100,000s). And then I shuffle that entire list, and then I trim it to the first 5. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Relationship.find_all_by_followee_id( user.id, :order => 'rand()', :limit => 5 ) do |follower|
   follower = User.find(follower.user_id)
   array.push follower
end
return array
```

Btw, this will work with MySql. If you are using PostgreSQL or anything else you may need to  change the `rand()` with any valid random function that your DB supports.

Some minor changes to make it a little more clean:

```
return Relationship.find_all_by_followee_id( user.id, :order => 'rand()', :limit => 5 ).collect {|follower| User.find(follower.user_id) }
```

You can also use a join in there in order to prevent the 5 selects but it won't make much difference.

Edit1:

As @mike.surowiec mentioned.

"Just for everyones benefit, translating this to the non-deprecated active record query syntax looks like this:"

```
Relationship.where(:followee_id => user.id).order( "random()" ).limit( 5 ).collect {|follower| User.find(follower.user_id) }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Also, thanks for the '.collect', I knew ruby could do automatic returns, but wasn't sure how with an array (if you couldn't tell, I come from a Java background).

Comment: Actually, in the second "cleaner" version, the return is unnecessary.

Comment: @Blizzo, you don't know the scope of the call. You are kind of right if its the code of the method and it only do that but that chunk of code can be part of a more complex flow. It may be part of an if block that can be cutting the current method execution.

Comment: Just for everyones benefit, translating this to the non-deprecated active record query syntax looks like this: Relationship.where(:followee_id => user.id).order( "random()" ).limit( 5 ).collect {|follower| User.find(follower.user_id) }

Comment: Thank you @mike.surowiec. I was working with a Rails 2.3 app and that was the safer answer I was able to submit.